# Amending css to percentages instead of pixels

Tags: css, wordpress, percent-encoding

I have recently created this WordPress [site](http://jamieflynnbase.com/home/) and have used pixels and margins to create the layout of the two semi-transparent content boxes. However, as I'm sure those more experienced than me are aware this is not at all responsive and not very cross browser friendly either! So I have been advised to swap to **percentages** rather than **pixels** but can't work out where to start with my existing CSS!

Will I need to make a layout with 5 columns to achieve this?

- first column blank to create left hand blank space
- second column to include larger blue content box
- third column blank to create space between two columns
- fourth column smaller blue content box
- fifth column to create far right hand blank space

Is there an easier way?

Here is a link to my existing [stylesheet](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=YsmR3mQT)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if I've forgotten to pass on some required information please just let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this:

1. Find the widest element. It's width, `XXXpx`, is going to be your new `100%`.
2. Find every other element with a `px` value, `YYYpx`. It's width is going to now be `(YYY/XXX * 100)px`.
3. Visually go over your site and make sure everything looks right. Not all styles are meant to be percentage based, so you will need to revert a few here and there.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't look too difficult to do, can I check I'll need 5 columns to create what I want? [http://jamieflynnbase.com/home/] Also, I have some code to make the background image fit & want to check if anything needs changing to this to make the above work? 'html, body {background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #FFCC33; 
line-height:1.4em; /* 16*1.4=18 */
}'

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [http://adapt.960.gs](http://adapt.960.gs/) if you want something more responsive ;)
It's quite easy to use:

You have to add the JS file at first:

```
<script src="js/adapt.min.js" type="test/javascript"></script>
```

Then CSS (as a fallback in case of JS is deactivated on user browser):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.min.css" />
```

At last some JS lines to tell browser to switch the CSS file depends on browser width:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
    path: 'assets/css/',
    range: [
      '0px    to 760px  = mobile.css',
      '760px  to 980px  = 720.css',
      '980px  to 1280px = 960.css',
      '1280px to 1600px = 1200.css',
      '1600px to 1920px = 1560.css',
      '1920px           = fluid.css'
    ]
  };
</script>
```

Then you will be able to use a standard grid in your HTML and it will adapt itself for every uses.
The page http://adapt.960.gs/ will provide you additional instruction and demo (try to resize your browser's window or visit it through your mobile) ;)